# How to check if list contains byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, design-patterns, contains

I have byte buffer:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
List<byte[]> list;
```

Now I am adding:

```
 while ((count = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
 {       
      bool contains = l.Contains<byte[]>(buffer); //This is not working and checking only reference 

      if (!contains)                          
      {                          
        l.Add(new byte[] buffer[0],buffer[1],buffer[2]});              
      }                
  }
```

How to check if list contains byte array wchich has the same values as buffer?

Comment: Please add a language tag to your question. (I am assuming C# but I am not sure)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current version is not working because it does a check based on *reference* equality.

You want to find out if any list elements contain the same sequence of bytes:

```
bool contains = list.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(buffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool ContainsSequence(byte[] toSearch, byte[] toFind) {
  for (var i = 0; i + toFind.Length < toSearch.Length; i++) {
    var allSame = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < toFind.Length; j++) {
      if (toSearch[i + j] != toFind[j]) {
        allSame = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (allSame) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```